# Using CAS without the Login Screen version3.5

Tags: single-sign-on, jasig

here is a old version:https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+Login+Screen

I need to do the same with that latest version of CAS i.e. 3.5 . Can anyone provide me the steps for the same

Answer (score 2):

We are doing now basically what you're asking here in my company. We have a Sharepoint website that in background is using the RESTful services for doing the real login. I wrote some posts about them in [my blog](http://hons82.blogspot.it/2012/07/cas-restlet-access.html) and recently we used it to get [access from a iOS application](http://hons82.blogspot.it/2013/01/cas-login-from-ios.html) which contains a link to a sample program.

Important!!! We have a modification in our CAS that offers the possibility to use it for more than one domain. So wherever you find a reference to something called "Domain" in my samples just remove it, as it will not work on standard CASes

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API) is a nice solution to your problem.

Just enable restful access.